# HTML5 validation of image tags

Tags: validation, html

Am I not allowed to specify the unit for width and height on `<img>` tags in HTML5?

I am getting this error from the validator:

> Bad value 122px for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Drop the 'px' part. [Use only non-negative integers](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html).

Comment: I know that's what it's asking me, but why so? I come from an XHTML background and am fond of `px` at the end. It seems normal. Why does it let me end the image tag with a short closing XML syntax, `<img/>` but doesn't let me specify px?

Comment: In [previous versions of HTML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html), other units were supported but pixels were the default. The HTML5 specification drops (wisely, in my opinion) support for other units. Anything more complex should be handled in CSS.

Comment: These tags never have had units, other than as a %. Remember that they are relics of the bad old days! http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/types.html#type-length

Comment: @Francisc: Can you provide a reference for that?

Comment: It's not true, XHTML doesn't specify (as it's not a difference from HTML4), and HTML4 doesn't allow it. style="width:100px;" is of course correct, but width=100px is wrong.

Comment: It seems I've been wrongly thinking it's mandatory. I couldn't find the proper reference, but the XHTML1.1 validator did not throw an error on `height="100px"` nor on `width="100"`.

Answer (score 7):

Move the percentage width from the html tag to the in-line style:

For example:

Change this line

```
<iframe width="100%" height="588" style="border:none; background:transparent; overflow:hidden;" />
```

to this:

```
<iframe height="588" style="border:none; background:transparent; overflow:hidden; width:100%;" />
```

then it will validate...

Answer (score 4):

just write 122 instead of 122p